# Image style not generated on page visit

Tags: media

I have a content type where users can upload pictures on. Now during the creation of the page, I upload with the widget from the media module. During that tume a square_thumbnail is made. I also have a view that generates a list of such contenttypes where the images have a different style. If I browse to that view none of the images are displayed. What I get is a file not found box ans the source file is supposed to be the home page. I Then go to views and on to the edit the specific view. If I press preview the view then all of a sudden all style image files are generated. So writing permissions should be fine. If I then watch the page with the view all is normal.

Does anybody know what is going on here? Also in the media module I i just upload a file under find content >> media the file is uploaded and an entry appears for that file but no thumbnail.

I have no idea what is happening, thoughts??